# Motivation for Event Bus in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, web-applications

I am creating an MVP-like application in GWT.

- There are multiple panels, and each one is visible at all times.
- Each panel has a Presenter, and there is a single AppController which sits above all Presenters.
- There are some application-level events which arise within one Presenter but have implications for other Presenters.
- The suggested architecture for this seems to involve an Event Bus. However, I'm not sure I see the advantage over something simpler.
- In particular, wouldn't it be cleaner to simply allow the AppController (and only the AppController) to subscribe to events from any Presenter? The AppController can then tell each Presenter what to do, given the event.
- The "Event Bus" seems like a quasi-global variable. But if you can accomplish the same thing with more precisely defined methods (i.e. the methods which AppController calls on each Presenter) isn't that preferable?

To put my concern more precisely: why introduce an Event Bus at all, rather than simply letting events "bubble up" to the appropriate decision-making level? To me this seems like the most straightforward extension of the MVP concept, and it doesn't require the new idea of an Event Bus. I don't understand what problem the Event Bus was introduced to solve.

Comment: I found GWT documentation for MVP confusing. You can find it here -  https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/mvp-architecture

Comment: SSR -- Thanks. I did read this documentation but, interestingly, there's no real motivation given for the event bus in that document. It just says "you'll want to rely on an Event Bus" which doesn't really clarify things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The advantage of the eventbus is separation of the code.

You can just fire custom events to the bus and don't need to care about your event anymore.
Every presenter subscribes only to that events, which it really needs to know. This will lead into cleaner code because, you don't have to create a dispatcher which has to know all presenter to delegate events to them.

In my opinion, the eventbus is a really good thing, to make the code clean and easily understandable.

Comment: Thanks for your response. When you say the alternative is to "create a dispatcher" I'm a little unclear about what you're referring to. Do you mean a dispatcher inside each Presenter, which must know about all other (subscribed) Presenters? I agree that sounds bad. Instead, what I mean is that the AppController receives application events and then simply tells the Presenters to **do** things (using public methods defined in the Presenters). In this scheme, the Presenters do not listen to events from other Presenters. Apologies if I'm missing something...

Comment: This approach will work, if you have only a few presenter. But if you think in a larger scale, lets say more than 20 - 100 presenter, than you will have to much logic in this single AppController. In fact this single class needs to know all presenter and has to dispatch events there. If you add a custom event to a presenter, you'll have to update your AppController too.

Comment: OK, this sounds like a pretty good reason. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

Your proposed approach is fine, with one big drawback: it calls for spaghetti code when your app grows.

[This presentation](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Android-Design) is about Android but the arguments hold for GWT too.

See also [this famous presentation](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/GoogleWebToolkitBestPractices.html) from Google I/O 2009 which explicitly talks about *Use an Event Bus to fight spaghetti code* (a *must-watch* if you haven't already).

Finally, [this blog post](http://freshbrewedcode.com/jimcowart/2013/02/07/client-side-messaging-essentials/) deals with the *observer* vs. *mediator* patterns in JS: in GWT, the *observer pattern* is realized by event handlers whereas the *mediator pattern* is realized by the event bus. Here's the *tl;dr*: « use observer “locally”, inside a component, mediator “remotely” between components. »

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. However, at least in the PDF version of the Google I/O presentation (I'm in Ethiopia so I don't have the bandwidth to watch the video) it appears that the described alternative to the Event Bus is direct presenter-to-presenter communication, which I agree becomes spaghetti-like.

What I am trying to describe is not quite that -- rather it's a situation where there is still a "mediator" or "broker" to hide Presenters from each other, but that mediator is a piece of logic (AppController) that sits "on top" of all the presenters.